# Copying file to multiple destinations

Tags: windows, copy

Is there a way to copy, at the same time, a single directory to multiple hard drives without the copy processes having each to read the source files? (Something like a Raid 1 perhaps)

In the specific, where I work we need to deploy (even multiple times a day) a folder containing around ~50gb of data from a PC (with Windows 7) to multiple others... using USB drives... (yup, usb drives, can't do anything about that). Often serially copying the files to each USB takes ages and it creates LONG dead times, especially for the last people to receive their copy.

Since the source PC in question has 8 USB 3.0 ports, would it be possible somehow to copy at the same time the source directory to USB drives in all 8 ports? (Of course without having 8 copy processes fighting for the limited read speed of the source hard drive... just readying each file and copying it to all destinations)

I tried searching for an answer but all I got were answers for linux or networked machines.

Comment: Why should multiple copy processes slow the reading down? That is what caches are for. As long as everything fits into RAM (Win7 takes up to 192 GiB of that, IIRC) , this should not be the bottleneck! - And as long as the USB drives have dedicated controllers, you could use them in parallel. If they are throttled by the controller, you can't do anything about that, anyway. In any case I cannot believe read speed should be the real problem. - Still off topic, though. ;)

Comment: Ideally yes, that's what should happen, load the file to RAM, send it to all devices from RAM. It seems windows didn't notice. At the end of the day I'll try writing something in C# to handle that. Unsure if I'll be able to, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/n2ncopy/
I've searched it on google, i have never tryed the program

Comment: Yup, I found that, it's pretty much useless, it takes the same time than copying everything one after another, maybe a bit more. :(
The only upside is that you don't have to manually copy the files to each drive.